# php mysqli synax error

Tags: php, mysql

what's wrong with my code? I'm sure `$_POST['item']` has valid value

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['item'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "ajaxexample");

$q = INSERT INTO user (userList) VALUES ('$data');
if(mysqli_query($conn, $q)){

echo 1;

}

?>
```

Comment: you look like you are missing some quotes. Rather than "being sure" why not just echo out the value of $data and check.

Comment: use `mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['item'] )` for security

Comment: show table name and structure

Comment: here is it : http://i.imgur.com/7L4IEDx.png

Answer (score 2):

put `INSERT INTO user (userList) VALUES ('$data');` in double quotes.

eg:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO user (userList) VALUES ('$data')";
```

Comment: I created a similar table like this ...I only found the "doublequotes" problem.it should be double quoted not single quoted.

Answer (score 1):

PHP string literals need to be in quotes.

To fix this by changing just one line:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO user (userList) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($data . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['item'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "ajaxexample");

$q = INSERT INTO user (userList) VALUES ('$data');
if(mysqli_query($conn, $q)){

echo 1;

}

?>

Not mysqli_select_db
```